# how to run command in console which you open in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, kitty

I am running a bash script in a Konsole window,
which opens a kitty console in a new window,
and I want to run a command already in this new kitten window,

how can I do that?

```
#!/bin/bash

kitty <some command which i wanna run in kitty>
```

Comment: The version of KDE would be helpful. Nonetheless, presuming it's not TDE (KDE3) which would use `dcop`, KDE4/Plasma can use `dbus`. Essentially you will use the inner-process communication language to launch konsole and then issue the command to run in that new session. In the old days that would be similar to `dcop KID SID sendSession yourcommand` where `KID` is the konsole ID and `SID` is the session ID. I don;t have a dbus example for you.

Comment: thanx for answer, qdbus works.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your konsole scripting. You can do a whole lot with `qdbus`. (and the older `dcop`) I have a script that runs that launches konsole and opens 9 konsole tabs and reestablishes `ssh` connections with 5 remote hosts, renaming the tabs with the remote hostnames and renaming and numbering the local tabs with the hostname plus  `-1`, `2`, .... Originally just written as a time-saving effort, it exposed what all can be done in KDE with the inter-process communications (and that's a lot!)

Answer (score -1):

kitty command-you-want-to-run arguments-for-the-command...

See
man kitty
or
kitty --help

for details

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).